# Error google map api

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I retrieve in my database addresses in Lat and Lng as well as various information .. when I only put in my table my points displayed correctly. But when I add the company name the script crashes. Here is my code

```
<?php

function getMarkers()
{
$pdo = connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM krys';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$locations = array();

foreach ($list as $row) {
    $company = $row['social'];
    $address = $row['adresse'];
    $cp = $row['cp'];
    $city = $row['ville'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $fax = $row['fax'];
    $tLat = (string)$row['latitude'];
    $tLng = (string)$row['longitude'];

    $locations[] = "[".$tLat .", ".$tLng.",".$company."]";
}

echo sprintf("[%s]",implode(", ", $locations));
}


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = <?php getMarkers(); ?>

function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 48.60222, lng: 2.42245};
    var image = {
        url: 'krys-markup.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(50, 55),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 55)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        console.log(locations);
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
            'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
            'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
            'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
            '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
            'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
            'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
            'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
            'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
            'Heritage Site.</p>'+
            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                infowindow.setContent('<div>test</div>');
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            }
        });
    }
    marker.setMap(map);
};
```

Show this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

If I remove $ company from php it works.

thank you.

Comment: Is `$company` supposed to be a number or a string? If it's a string, you need to put quotes around it. `$locations[] = "[".$tLat .", ".$tLng.",'".addslashes($company)."']";`

Comment: @Christopher Consider http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php